# 2nd order ODE with specific substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was wondering what the solution of:

$$yy''+(y')^2=yy'+e^x$$ if I'm obliged to use the substitution $$v=yy'$$

I tried replacing the y's by this substitution but it doesn't really get me anywhere and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, if $v = yy'$, then by the product rule,

$$v' = (y')^2 + yy''$$

Then your equation becomes

$$v' = v + e^x$$

Comment: I got $$v= e^x(x+c)$$ But I need the solution of y. If I simply plug in my v into the initial equation $$v= yy'$$ then I will have a y in my equation, which is not good. How would I find the solution of y now? @EeveeTrainer

Comment: @agg199 you get $y y’ = e^x(x+c)$ which you can solve by separation of variables

Answer (score 0):

$$yy''+(y')^2=yy'+e^x$$
$$(yy')'=yy'+e^x$$
$$(yy')'e^{-x}-(yy')e^{-x}=1$$
$$(yy'e^{-x})'=1$$
$$((y^2)'e^{-x})'=2$$
Or you can keep it this way:
$$(ve^{-x})'=1$$
Integrate twice.